# setLocation() from UI.init() method

Tags: java, redirect, vaadin

Is it possible to use getPage().setLocation(...) from the init() method of UI. I have to redirect user to external site, under certain conditions. So far, it does not work (Vaadin 7.0.2).

Here is the code example:

```
@Override
public void init(VaadinRequest request) {
   if (myCondition) 
      getPage().setLocation("http://www.externalsite.com");
   else {
      ....
   }     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. I used old version of WidgetSet, which was left from 6.X times, and was not re-compiled with Vaadin 7. After I fixed it - it works fine.

Comment: Great. Did you miss cleaning out the gwt compilation caches? That got me as well. For others who might be having the same issue, this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15575783/1218899

Answer (score 1):

That's strange that it isn't working for you... `setLocation` is all you need. Here is a working version: [VaadinLocationRedirect](https://github.com/cpoile/VaadinLocationRedirect).  `mvn package` will build the widgetset, `mvn jetty:run` will host it.  Let us know what the problem was if you figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you can call the [`open( URL )`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html#open%28com.vaadin.terminal.Resource%29) method of the Window object to open another URL in the same or a new browser window to achieve the redirection to an external site.

As an alternative you can set the exit URL for the application via `application.setExitUrl()` call and then close the application by calling `application.close()` - your application session will be closed and browser redirected to the specified address.

Comment: -1 sorry. All of this approaches are not applicable to Vaadin 7. Ironically javadoc linked in this answer doesn't have `open` method.