# Compiling Vaadin Addon using Ant

Tags: gwt, ant, vaadin

I am using add on called ICEPush to push data Async to the client. BTW I am using vaadin 7. when ever I open the page it throws me the following error

```
Widgetset does not contain implementation for org.vaadin.artur.icepush.ICEPush. Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions.
```

I am using ant as my build script. Can you some one pls help me with steps to Compile the Addon?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Pretty long, but better late then never.

I created a new task which has dependency on my sources.

```
<target name="build-widgetset" if="widgetset">
        <java classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler" failonerror="yes"
            fork="yes">
            <arg value="-war" />
            <arg value="${webroot}/VAADIN/widgetsets" />
            <arg value="${widgetset}" />
            <arg value="-logLevel" />
            <arg value="DEBUG" />
            <arg value="-strict" />
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M" />
            <jvmarg value="-Djava.awt.headless=true" />
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="${sources}" />
                <pathelement path="${workdir}" />
                <path refid="classpath" />
            </classpath>
            <sysproperty key="vFailIfNotSerializable" value="true" />
        </java>

        <!-- cleanup -->
        <delete dir="${webroot}/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache" />
        <delete dir="${webroot}/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF" />
    </target>
```

`Classpath` - Classpath of all Vaadin libraries 
`widgetset` - Widgetset that needs to be compiled - would be something like `com.vaadin.mywidgetset` 
`webroot` - Root of web directory where compiled sources are placed, In Eclipse it would be `WebContent` directory 
`sources` - reference to your source directory
`workdir` - Temporary directory to place processed files temporarily

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need to debug the problem. How familiar are you with widgetset compilation?
Have you set up your AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml correctly? Have you cleaned all previous widgetset intermediate artifacts from your src directory?

(This has caused me pain in the past, especially when moving from Vaadin 6 to 7. I have a specific maven clean goal that I uncomment when moving Vaadin versions so that it deletes the `/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets` and `/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache` directories. Otherwise it won't completely recompile the widgetset.)

Finally, have you run the Ant-specific command to recompile the Vaadin widgetset?

I hate to answer with this type of answer, but is there a specific reason you are using Ant? If not, you can use the maven pom that is created when you generate a Vaadin 7 project using these instructions: [from the wiki](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20Maven%20project).

Add the following plugin command to the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
     <configuration>
         <filesets>
             <fileset>
                 <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                 <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache</directory>
             </fileset>
         </filesets>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then run: `mvn clean vaadin:clean package` and you'll be fine.

Comment: I ran Ant specific command to compile the widget, I believe there is some config that is missing, I am debugging that issue right now. Hmmm we have our product on Ant so not getting away with it.